# как обращаться к базе данных room, в корутине?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, coroutine, kotlinx-coroutines

```
suspend fun dblistasinc() = coroutineScope{
    launch{
        }
    }
}
```

значит есть такой код, как мне в нем сделать обращение к базе данных,
вернее я знаю как сделать обращение к базе но я не понимаю как это сделать по людски,
типо:

```
suspend fun dblistasinc() = coroutineScope{
    launch{
        var db = notesdb.notedbfunc(this)
        db.gdao().getAllnotes()
        }
    }
}
```

если я сделаю вот так, то заработает, но при попытке присвоить еще одно значение базы данных другой перемменной получается ошибка, и как это использовать я не могу ни присвоить это значение ни передать значения функции за пределы функции
подскажите пожалуйста как работать с корутинами в kotlin, я запутался

Comment: launch вам не нужен.

Comment: подскажите правильный вариант написания функции(suspend-корутины) и её запуске пожалуйста, с функцией получения объектов из базы данных

Comment: Ваша `dblistasinc` сама по себе корутина. Уберите launch и coroutineScope, и оставьте остальное. А launch будет выше по уровню - обычно `viewModelScope.launch {...}`